# toggle button vs image changing button

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

When to use this functionality and when to use the other? I personally thing that to switch between two different modes one should use a toggle button but i need to convince some people at work. any formal UI literature on the subject? thanks

Comment: Just to make sure I'm clear toggle button = `<input type="submit"/>` and image changing button = `<input type="image"/>`?

Comment: not at all. hmm I thought these were pretty clear. 

toggle is a button which has two modes, pressed and not pressed. 
and some people prefer to programatically change the icon of the button after every click. like start-stop buttons. usually they have a triangle play sign and after you click on them they have a square stop sign.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have references for you, but as a user I can tell you what I would expect.

I would expect the button to change images when you substitute one action for another because you entered a different mode.  This is really relevant to save real estate in your toolbars, etc.  For example you *could* have a dedicated play button and stop button with one always being disabled.  Using one button saves space since at no point will both be enabled.

I would expect a normal depressed/unpressed toggle button when there is one mode that you either enable or disable.  An example of this is "Toggle Mark Occurrences" in Eclipse.  Unpressing that toggle button does not constitute a new action, but rather disabling an active mode.

Answer (score 1):

I’m inclined to go with toggling buttons (buttons that “stick” depressed when “on”) rather than swapping images or label for a command button. I can’t cite any formal literature, but my impression is that it makes it easier both to anticipate the action produced by activation and to read the current state. The appearance and behavior of a toggle button is consistent with physical toggle button switches (like the Play buttons on older physical tape recorders). It’s also consistent with option buttons, check boxes, and state menu items, which all indicate their affirmative states through peripheral graphic design rather than labels. When the control looks like a command button (raised appearance), it’s labeled like a command button, the label indicating the action committed like any command button (e.g., “Connect”). When it looks like a state indicator (sunken, like a text box), its labeled suggest its current state (connected).

A single toggle button should only be used when there are simple True and False states to the process (e.g., Connected or not). Otherwise you need two or more “segmented controls” (abutting toggling buttons) to ambiguously indicate the alternatives (e.g., Forward vs. Reverse). This is analogous to using two option buttons in place of a check box.

Swapping labels to indicate changes in a button’s action can work if you use *text* labels that unambiguously indicate the action committed on activation, e.g., (“Connect” and “Disconnect”). While the Play/Pause button is a defacto standard, I’d otherwise avoid using an icon or image because it may confuse users on whether the label is indicating the *current* state or the state they’d get on activation (i.e., the opposite). There have been buttons that do one or the other, so the user can’t rely on experience. An image it not clearly a verb or adjective, so labeling with an image is tantamount to using text labels like “Online” and “Offline.” Even if done right, swapping labels has the disadvantage that the user needs to do a weird mental transformation to read the affirmative state (“It says I can disconnect, therefore I must be online now”). It can also mean you need a wordier label.