# Image Changing Button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027618/javascript-background-image-changing-button) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405515/toggle-button-vs-image-changing-button) for my answer but found that the code was far too long for such a simple process.
Below, my code shows a basic Image Changer by having the 'image' changed to the different .jpg's in an array, located in the same file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img id="image" src="blank_light.jpg" style="width:100px">
<p></p>
<button class = "change-image">Change Lights</button>
<script>
var imageSources = ["green_light.jpg", "yellow_light.jpg", "red_and_yellow_light.jpg", "red_light.jpg", "blank_light.jpg"]
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("change-image")
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("image").src = imageSources[i]
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In theory, because I've embedded the script within the HTML it should work like a dream, but the image seems to get stuck on the yellow light. Is there a repeat button click phase I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You have only one button, and when you click on it you set the `src` of the image to the first image in the Array (which is `green_light.jpg`).

Comment: This code would make sense if you had multiple buttons. But since you want to walk through the array on each click, you need at least a variable that stores the current array index. Clicking the button should advance the variable, then use that to get the filename from the array.

Comment: @Dekel would you recommend creating the variable for the array index as Chris said, or creating more buttons? Of course adding more buttons may make things look untidy, but with a basic knowledge of JS and HTML I would probably struggle with making the index unless somebody were to post it as an answer _*hint hint*_

Comment: @ChrisG As with you Chris, what do you think of what I've said above?

Comment: @freddie.bumder What exactly are you referring to? Paul's answer should work fine btw, if you change `index++` to `index = (index + 1) % imageSources.length`

Comment: @ChrisG the image didn't change at all

Comment: @freddie.bumder The code works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/q2f6gp3s/

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for all the help, code's working and task has been completed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use a loop. You can get reference to the button using `document.getElementsByClassName("change-image")[0];`. Then you can add an event lister to trigger on each button click.

Each time a user clicks you iterate through the array by one.

You could look at doing something like this:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("change-image")[0];
var index = 0;

buttons.addEventListener('click',function() {
    if(index === imageSources.length ) {
        index = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("image").src = imageSources[index];
    index++;
});
```

Here is the complete code, which works. If you inspect the `img` element you will see that it updates.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <img id="image" src="blank_light.jpg" style="width:100px">
    <p></p>
    <button class="change-image">Change Lights</button>
    <script>
      var imageSources = ["green_light.jpg", "yellow_light.jpg", "red_and_yellow_light.jpg", "red_light.jpg", "blank_light.jpg"]
      var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("change-image")[0];
      var index = 0;

      buttons.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (index === imageSources.length) {
          index = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById("image").src = imageSources[index];
        index++;
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried using your code, but upon clicking the button, the image didn't change at all, even after trying @Chris G's approach

Comment: @freddie.bumder the code definitely works. are you sure you are referencing the images correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Funny implementation -))

```js
document.getElementById("changer").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var i = document.getElementById("source"); 
  var images = [
    "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports",
    "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals",
    "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature"
  ];
  
  var ord = parseInt(i.dataset.order); 
  
  nextImage = function(prev) {
    return (prev+1 >= images.length ? (prev + 1)%images.length : prev+1);
  }
  
  document.getElementById("source").src = images[nextImage(ord)];
  i.dataset.order = ord + 1; 
  
})
```

```html
<img id="source" data-order="0" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports">
<button id="changer">change</button>
```